# Java implementation of this - calling a Parent class method to utilizing Child class data member

Tags: java, inheritance, this, super

This question is regarding **Implementation Decision** of `super` and `this` in Java. Consider,

Parent class contains a variable `name` and a method `getName()`

```
public class Parent {

    protected String name = "Parent";

    protected String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

And Child class inherits Parent class but has its own `name` variable

```
public class Child extends Parent {

    protected String name = "Child";

    protected void printNames() {
        System.out.println("Parent: " + super.getName());
        System.out.println("Child: " + this.getName());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Child c = new Child();
        c.printNames();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Parent: Parent
Child: Parent
```

From output, we can see that: *When the method `getName()` is invoked from Child class with `super` context, it returns "Parent", but when invoked with `this` context, it again returns "Parent"*

**If the method is only present in Parent class, but the data members with same access modifier present in both,**

**Why shouldn't `this.getName()` from Child class return "Child" because it *`is-a`* Parent thus has `getName()` as its method**

**UPDATE**
This question is not about how to get "Child" printed or overriding, its about implementation decision of `this` by Core Java Team, and its intended for them.

Comment: You didn't override the getName method, and variables can't be overriden, so that's why you see Parent

Comment: If you have a question for Core Java team, then you would better ask that question on one of the mailing lists they follow. You can find a list here: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/mailman/listinfo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fields are not `overridable` only methods are, the fields can only be hidden or not. `this` actually refers to the current `Object` which is of type `Parent` in the method  `Parent#getName()` such that it will get the value of the variable name defined in `Parent` or potentially a parent class but not in a sub class like `Child`.

Here is a simple code snippet that shows the idea:

```
Child child = new Child();
// Show the variable name of the class Child
System.out.println(child.name);
// Show the variable name of the class Parent which is what this.name 
// does in the getName method
System.out.println(((Parent)child).name);
```

**Output:**

```
Child
Parent
```

Answer (score 1):

If u want to get 'child' as output you have to override the getname() method otherwise it is inherited,it will always show the 'parent' as output.

Answer (score 0):

Just override the `getName()` method in your Child class

```
@Override
protected String getName() {
    return name;
}
```

#### Update

If you don't want to override the `getName()` method, you can do like this :

- set the `name` value in the `Child` constructor since it is a `protected` attribute
- do not override the `name` attribute anymore in the `Child` class

  ```
  public class Child extends Parent {
      public Child() {
          super();
          this.name = "Child";
      }
      // ...
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a getName() method to the child class.  Right now, when you invoke this.getName(), the parent version is called since it is not overridden in the child class.